# How do compound adjectives semantically work?

Tags: compounds

For example, there are words, “omnipotent” and “godlike.” If two words are combined, does “omnipotent godlike” mean “like an omnipotent god”?

…be described using five terms: “green-unripe”, “green-peapod”, “green-grassy/leafy”, “green-viney”, and “green-fruity”, and food examples of these green...

Comment: Your example is unclear, because we don't combine adjectives with a dash like that.  Can you find an example in a real English text?

Comment: Please provide a source for your quote.  This is from https://www.proquest.com/openview/fef2cbd540312e2f1cb41a8eb85385db/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=18750  which makes it clear that "green" is a **flavour** and not a colour!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Omnipotent godlike"  would mean "with unlimited power *and* like a god".  Generally adjectives combine with an implicit "and".  A big red ball is both big and red.

Your example with "green" is technical.  The author is using "green" as an odour which they subclassify into five types of "green" flavour.  These are technical terms that experienced tasters might use to describe subtle differences between the flavours of different food (tomatoes in this case)

Comment: For example, green fruity means “green flavoured and fruity”? not “like green flavoured fruit”?

Comment: It means that flavour that tasters describe as the "fruity" type of the green flavour. But this is not a common usage.  It would be a technical term